# Ionic 3 ion-datetime component and "ion-date-selected" event

Tags: angular, events, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm new to AngularJS and got a problem with Ionic - I got a simple form, where I need to display a notification (Ionic's alert) if user selects particular date using *ion-datetime* component. In specification we can find *ion-cancel* event but there is nothing like *ion-date-selected*.

Is there a way I could detect, that user selected a date? *ionChange* doesn't do a job either, because it's being fired multiple times. I know, I can subscribe to the model and check if has changed but maybe there is a better/simpler way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can use the following code in your **page.html**:

```
   <ion-item>
  <ion-label>Date</ion-label>
  <ion-datetime displayFormat="MM/DD/YYYY" [(ngModel)]="myDate" (ngModelChange)="dateChanged()"></ion-datetime>
</ion-item>
```

and in **your page.ts**:

```
myDate:any
dateChanged(){
if (myDate== testDate){
// your code here
}
}
```

Comment: This works well! Also, I could use (ionBlur) event too. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Mark this as an accepted answer to help other people.